# Add an array into Bootstrap DateTimePicker options

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm attempting to disable certain dates in the Bootstrap Date Time Picker by eonasdan found [here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

I'm able to manually add an array of dates that then become disabled but I can't figure out how to add an array created dynamically into this option.

Here is my code:

```js
noDates = ['31/03/2017', '19/04/2017', '20/04/2017', '25/04/2017'];

// Just for testing
console.log(noDates);

// Studio 1 datepicker
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    // Date format
    format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
    // Show calendar when user clicks input field
    allowInputToggle: true,
    // Minimum date is today's date
    minDate: new Date(),
    // Disabled Dates
    disabledDates: noDates
});
```

Where it says `disabledDates: noDates` I am able to manually write out the dates like so:

```js
disabledDates: [
    "03/31/2017",
    "04/19/2017",
    moment("04/20/2017"),
    moment("04/25/2017")
]
```

I have also attempted the following:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').data('DateTimePicker').disabledDates(noDates);
```

However, that gives me the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'disabledDates' of undefined
```

Is there a way to add variables/arrays into objects like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your dates, more specific the format:

Wrong:

```
var noDates = ['31/03/2017', '19/04/2017', '20/04/2017', '25/04/2017'];
```

OK:

```
var noDates = ['2017-03-31', '2017-04-19', '2017-04-20', '2017-04-25'];
```

Comment: Sorry, would you be able to give me a little explanation? The only difference I see with that and my code is the `var` but that makes no difference when I add it?

Comment: AMAZING! Thanks very much! That makes me wonder though: How is it okay to add that exact array into the datetimepicker function but I can't do it using a variable?

Comment: The `disabledDates` expects an array.

Comment: Okay, still slightly confused as it was an array all along, it just had the date format wrong?

Comment: Yes. That was the only problem.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks very much!